# How to map data of entire Subcollection of Document and make it a Stream in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

i have a Firestore like the following :

[image]

My goal is to map each entry from the collection of days -> 'uid' -> collection to a datamodel called "Day" and return it as a stream to Provider.

Every entry in this collection in a date, which is holding a reference to a transfer. 
This is the transfer storage :

[image]
This is the Day Datamodel :

```
class Day {
  Day({this.date, this.transfers});

  final String date;
  final List<Transfer> transfers;
}
```

This is the code i tried (which is currently missing the deserializing of the List of Transfers, but i was lost at this point) :

```
  Stream<List<Day>> get dayTransferData {
    return daysCollection.document('QeG5SgSoYPXCpPkU86Z9ReShr2j2').collection('').snapshots().map(_brewListFromSnapshot);
  }

  List<Day> _brewListFromSnapshot(QuerySnapshot snapshot) {
    return snapshot.documents.map((doc) {
      return Day(
        date: doc.documentID,
        transfers: doc.data.values,
      );
    }).toList();
  }
```

I searched on stackoverflow but everyone was referencing the collection by name.

How do i get the data of the collection and map it in the correct way ?

Answer (score 0):

**User class with JSON convert: [JSON and serialization](https://flutter.dev/docs/development/data-and-backend/json)**

```
class User {
  String name;
  int age;

  User({
    this.name,
    this.age,
  });

  factory User.fromJson(String str) => User.fromMap(json.decode(str));

  String toJson() => json.encode(toMap());

  factory User.fromMap(Map<String, dynamic> json) => User(
        name: json["name"],
        age: json["age"],
      );

  Map<String, dynamic> toMap() => {
        "name": name,
        "age": age,
      };
}
```

**Create user list :**

```
users = jsonList.map((json) => User.fromJson(json)).toList();
```

Comment: How do i get the data from collection ?

Comment: https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/get-data